# How to initial exist image matrix with snap svg?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

Thanks [lan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1429053/ian) who helped me to complete svg transform with slider [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/david7418/jy9noyf5/1/).

After some progresses I got another problem about it.If the image has exist matrix, how should I apply it to the slider at the beginning? As Fiddle example, the image behavior looks strange while I drag the slider.

```
$(function() {
    Snap.plugin(function(Snap, Element, Paper, global) {
        Element.prototype.updateTransform = function() {
            var newTransform = 't' + (this.data('xy').x) + ',' + (this.data('xy').y);
            newTransform += 'r' + (this.data('r'))
            newTransform += 's' + (this.data('s'))
            this.transform(newTransform)
            return this;
        }
        Element.prototype.init = function() {
            return this.data('xy', {
                    x: 0,
                    y: 0
                })
                .data('r', 0)
                .data('s', 1)
        }

    });

    function dragStart(x, y) {
        this.data('oxy', this.data('xy'));
    }

    function dragMove(dx, dy, x, y) {
        this.data('xy', {
                x: this.data('oxy').x + dx,
                y: this.data('oxy').y + dy
            })

            .updateTransform();
    }
    obj = Snap(".cat");
    obj.init();
    obj.drag(dragMove, dragStart);

    //Slider resize
    $("#slider_resize").slider({
        max: 4,
        min: 1,
        step: 0.1,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            obj.data('s', ui.value)
                .updateTransform();
        }
    });
    //Slider rotate
    $("#slider_rotate").slider({
        max: 360,
        min: 0,
        step: 1,
        value: 0,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            obj.data('r', ui.value)
                .updateTransform();
        }
    });

    //Reset button
    $('#reset').click(function() {
        $("#slider_resize").slider('value', 0);
        $("#slider_rotate").slider('value', 0);
        obj.init().updateTransform();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the initial transform, and then add it on each time to the start of the new transform..so relevant bits would be...

In our init function, check if we have stored an initial transform, if not store it. We only want to do this once (otherwise you can't use the reset button).

```
if( !this.data('origTransform') ) this.data('origTransform', this.transform())
```

In the update transform function, we can add the original transform to the new one which we are manipulating, e.g

```
this.transform( this.data('origTransform') + newTransform )
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jy9noyf5/3/)

This 'may' be what you want, depending on what's in that initial transform (as subsequent transforms are affected by it). It may start to get very complicated if it isn't, as matrices aren't really reversable (eg the proper translation from a matrix) otherwise, but there may be a way depending on requirements :). I would test it with an initial rotation and scale on the image and see if it does what you want (if that's what you will end up supporting).

Comment: Thanks a lot!! You saved my life :DDD. The answer almost solved the problem. I have applied it to my project. It works good except drag and move. https://youtu.be/zg2bFLzUXf4. As the demo video shows, different original matrix causes different moving situation. Is this solvable?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. It should be different original image width and height causes different moving situation.

Comment: If  keep dragging the image, the browser gets slower and slower.  It's really strange....Should I try translate and change image width and height without matrix to deal with this? This is what I have done https://jsfiddle.net/o497akje/7/ . But this one also has a lots of problems if I give it initial matrix. I don't know what to do now..any suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, I gave you too many messages at once. I just found browser gets slower bug. That my problem. Please ignore it.

Comment: The easiest way is to put the image inside a <g> element and put the drag on that, eg https://jsfiddle.net/jy9noyf5/8/

Comment: Genius!! I love you lan! Everything works find now. Thank you thank you.